# Square gets stuck when it reaches the bottom of the canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, game-physics

I am trying to make a simple JavaScript based game, where the user would move the square around the canvas and dodge elements / squares coming towards it (however this is just a plan, I am far from that point at the moment).

The problem I am experiencing is that whenever I would make my canvas width value bigger than height, it would make the square get stuck after reaching the bottom of the page. There is probably an error / mistake in my code, however I could not seem to spot anything.

The code can be found [here](https://codepen.io/iph03nix/pen/qvNJRG?editors=1010) or below:

```js
    // This code was created in CodePen.io, so some parts of it might not make any sense,
    // nor are they gonna be useful outside the CodePen platform. Those parts are however only commented.

    var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
    var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // character data
    var charPositionX = canvas.width / 2;
    // Just for the snippet height
    var charPositionY = 0;
    //var deltaCharPositionX = 10;
    //var deltaCharPositionY = 10;

    //Removed the init() function, since the elements are loaded.

    // start creating elements, first the game environment.
    function draw() {
      clear();
      createRectangleToCoverCanvas();
      createChar(charPositionX, charPositionY, 10);
    }

    function clear() {
      ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    }

    function createRectangleToCoverCanvas() {
      ctx.fillStyle = '#ddd';
      ctx.strokeStyle = '#ddd';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }
    // now the character
    function createChar(x, y, radius) {
      ctx.fillStyle = 'white';
      ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
      ctx.beginPath();
      ctx.rect(x, y, 32, 32);
      ctx.fill();
      ctx.stroke();
    }

    var raf, 
      direction = {
      x: 0,
      y: 0
    };
 
    // set the speed variable for the character
    var speed = 5;
    function triggerMoveChar(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        // left
        case 37:
          // update the direction object
          direction.x = -speed;
          // avoid the scrolling
          event.preventDefault();
          break;

        // up
        case 38:
          direction.y = -speed;
          event.preventDefault();
          break;

        // right
        case 39:
          direction.x = speed;
          event.preventDefault();
          break;
        
        //down
        case 40:
          direction.y = speed;
          event.preventDefault();
          break;
      }
      // if the animation haven't been initiated yet, and the direction is not 0, then do it now
      if (!raf && (direction.x || direction.y)) moveChar();
    }

    function releaseMoveChar(event) {
      switch (event.keyCode) {
        // left
        case 37:
          //reset this direction
          direction.x = 0;
          break;
        
        // up
        case 38:
          direction.y = 0;
          break;
        
        // right
        case 39:
          direction.x = 0;
          break;
        
        //down
        case 40:
          direction.y = 0;
          break;
      }
      if (!direction.x && !direction.y) {
        // if none of the directions is set, stop the animation
        cancelAnimationFrame(raf);
        raf = undefined;
      }
    }

    function moveChar() {
      // declare the animation function
      var move = function() {
        // update the positions without going out of the screen
        if(direction.x){
         if(
        (charPositionX > 0 && charPositionX < canvas.width-32) ||
       (charPositionX <= 0 && direction.x > 0) ||
       (charPositionX >= canvas.width-32 && direction.x < 0))
      charPositionX += direction.x;
      }
      if(direction.y){
       if((charPositionY > 0 && charPositionY < canvas.height-32) ||
       (charPositionY <= 0 && direction.y > 0) ||
       (charPositionY >= canvas.width-32 && direction.y < 0))
      charPositionY += direction.y;
      }

        // finally draw ou character
        draw();
        // update the raf id
        raf = requestAnimationFrame(move);
      };
    // let's go !
    raf = requestAnimationFrame(move);
    }


    draw();

    window.addEventListener('keydown', triggerMoveChar, true);
    window.addEventListener('keyup', releaseMoveChar, true);
```

```css
    canvas {
      margin: auto;
      position: absolute;
      left: 0;
      top: 0;
      right: 0;
      bottom: 0;
      border: 3px solid red;
    }

    body {
      background: #222;
    }

    .container {
      color: #999;
      margin: 0;
      padding: 10px 0px 20px;
      font-family: "Orbitron", "Helvetica", sans-serif;
      text-align: center;
      font-size: 11px;
      line-height: 16px;
    }

    .container h1 {
      margin: 10px 0;
      color: red;
      font-size: 32px;
      min-height: 430px;
    }

    .container h2 {
      margin: 10px 0;
      color: #ccc;
      font-size: 24px;
      min-height: 10px;
    }

    .container h3 {
      margin: 10px 0;
      color: #999;
      font-size: 18px;
    }
```

```html
    <div class="container">
        <canvas id="canvas" width="640" height="416"></canvas>
        <h1>Project : Simple Game [v0.1alpha]</h1>
        <h2>CONTROLS: </h2>
        <h3>Arrow Keys </h3>
    </div>
```

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: It's unclear from the post if "getting stuck" is your problem or desired result.

Comment: Sorry to hear that the question was unclear to you, @hindmost, but as the second paragraph says, "The problem I am experiencing is that whenever I would make my canvas width value bigger than height, it would make the square get stuck after reaching the bottom of the page." The problem was that the square would get stuck at the bottom of the page when trying to make canvas width value bigger than the value of height. Thanks for stopping by though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on this line

```
if(direction.y){
          if((charPositionY > 0 && charPositionY < canvas.height-32) ||
                (charPositionY <= 0 && direction.y > 0) ||
                (charPositionY >= canvas.width-32 && direction.y < 0)) // here
                  charPositionY += direction.y;
            }
```

It should be `height` not `width`.

`(charPositionY >= canvas.height-32 && direction.y < 0))`

Comment: Thanks a lot! Don't know how I missed that :D